# Genexus. NotificationsRegistrationHandler procedure does not run

Tags: notifications, genexus

I develop in Genexus 16u10 and I have the disadvantage that the procedure is not executed, despite having reviewed the documentation and therefore I am not saving the tokens of each device. The properties are:

```
Panel for Smart Device (Main Program):
Main Program = True
Enable Notifications = True
Notifications - Registration Handler = NotificationsRegistrationHandler
```

[image: Procedure properties and generator properties]

Procedure code:

```
for each
   where DeviceType = &DeviceType // enum domain SmartDeviceType
   where DeviceId  = &DeviceId   // Character(128)
   DeviceToken = &DeviceToken    // Character(1000)
   DeviceName = &DeviceName       // Character(128)
when none
   new
      DeviceType  = &DeviceType
      DeviceId = &DeviceId
      DeviceToken = &DeviceToken
      DeviceName = &DeviceName
   endnew
endfor
```

I hope your help thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you add a PARM in rules section.

parm(in:&DeviceType, in:&DeviceID, in:&DeviceToken, in:&DeviceName);

Comment: Yes, its all. but it works put on true the property: Exposed at webservice.